# Why my future builder doesn,t work that is inside a future builder in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

```
   
void main() {
 runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
 const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
 late Future<bool> _forWifiChecking;
 Future? _future;

 Future<dynamic> sendData() async {
   final data1 = await wifiCheckConnection();
   final data2 = await checkConnection();
   final data3 = await checkServerState().timeout(
     const Duration(seconds: 5),
     onTimeout: () {
       return false;
     },
   );
   return [data1, data2, data3];
 }

 @override
 void initState() {
   _future = sendData();
   _forWifiChecking = checkWifi();
   super.initState();
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
     home: Scaffold(
       body: FutureBuilder(
           future: _future,
           builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
             if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
               return const LoadingWid();
             }
             if (snapshot.hasError) {
               return const LoadingWid();
             }
             final data1 = snapshot.data[0];

             if (data1 == true) {
             } else {
//if this isn't true i won't to display this future. What it will do i will check wifi connection untill the wifi connects. at the moment i won't display a wifi error page
               FutureBuilder(
                   future: _forWifiChecking,
                   builder: (context, snapshot) {
                     if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                       return const WifiErr();
                     }
                     if (snapshot.hasError) {
                       return const LoadingWid();
                     }
                     return const LoadingWid();
                   });
             }

             return const ServerErr();
           }),
     ),
   );
 }
}
```

What i am trying do is i have app, first when running the app i won't to check if there is wifi connected and if not send the user to a page that says wifi connecting and in the backend it will check for wifi until wifi connectes. after user connected to wifi i what to display a wifi connected page and then the app will check for my server state.if server is not ok i will send user to a page displaying server not connected and in the backend of the app it check the server state until its ok. if it is ok then user will go to home page

Comment: what doesn't work?

Comment: the functions work. that means the fuctions that is user to chechk wifi and my server state. those return ture or false. according to those true or false i need to display pages. i don,t know how to get it work.

Comment: There isn't implementations for _future and _forWifiChecking in the given code.

Comment: Are you able to get true or false? Is the value is what you're expecting?

Comment: yes i did mange to get true or false

Comment: There isn't implementations for _future and _forWifiChecking in the given code.

Comment: add return keyword for second FutureBuilder()

return FutureBuilder(
                   future: _forWifiChecking,
                   builder: (context, snapshot) {
                     if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                       return const WifiErr();
                     }
                     if (snapshot.hasError) {
                       return const LoadingWid();
                     }
                     return const LoadingWid();
                   });